# PIR sensor detecting continuosly therefore loop counter( "i") may be not incrementing and loop stay in a idle state

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, 8051, microprocessors

My project  is: Read temperature and send it through SMS with 10 min span, and within this span if there is any motion then send SMS "MOTION DETECTED".

so, just for testing i used two LED one for temperate( it will stay on for 10 min) SMS and another for MOTION (it will blink once) and commented function call statement i.e. sendMessage ,sendMsg

everything is working fine but problem is " when i keeping and shaking continuously for a long time my hand in front of the PIR sensor , it continuously detecting motion and may be counter is not increasing therefore dled i.e. 1st one for temp stay on more than 10 min..., but if i keep my hand in front of the PIR sensor for a few sec just to detect Motion( as many time as i want) then its working fine... but for continuous detection something happening for what dled stay on more than 10 min..for example for 30 sec continuous detection dled stay on 10 min 30 sec ...for 1 min dled stay on 11mins..."

this is the problem hope i make you guys make it understandable... 
so please help me out.. thanks

here is the code below...

```
#include <DHT.h>                 //DHT sensor
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>      //this is a constructor for gsm
#include<LiquidCrystal.h>        //this is for LCD display
#include "DHT.h"          
#define DHTPIN 8                 //blue 8 define pins for DHT
#define DHTTYPE DHT11 // DHT11  
#define pir 6                    //yellow 6 
#define pled 13                  //for PIR led
#define dled 7                   //for DHT led

DHT dht(DHTPIN,DHTTYPE);
int pirState=LOW;

int prival=0;

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
SoftwareSerial mySerial(9, 10);  //9-->Rx;  10-->Tx



void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("SMS ALERT");
  pinMode(pir,INPUT);           //set pir pin as input
  dht.begin();
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  pinMode(pled,OUTPUT);       //LED for pir sensor... "set pled pin as output"
  pinMode(dled,OUTPUT);       //LED for DHT sensor... "set dled pin as output"


}
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:


 // block for sending temp information...
float t=dht.readTemperature();
Serial.print("Temperature: ");
Serial.println(t);
Serial.println("SMS INITIATING...");
// SendMessage(t);  to sent temp...

/*stay HIGH for 10 min..when loop will end pin will be low i.e. LED will be  
 off then again for new loop it will be on ..and it will continue... */
digitalWrite(dled,HIGH);                

Serial.println("DONE...");
lcd.print("Temp is: ");
lcd.print(t);
lcd.print((char)223);
lcd.print("C    ");
delay(500);

//checking pir sensor.. whether motion is detected or not..
//when motion is detected sent msg "MOTION DETECTED" 
//and loop will continue for 10 min span

int i=0;
   while(i!=600){
      prival=digitalRead(pir);      //read pir pin  = 6
      if(prival==HIGH)
      {
        if(pirState==LOW)
        {
           Serial.println("Motion detected");
           Serial.print("Temp is: ");
           Serial.print(t);
           Serial.print((char)223);
           Serial.println("C");
           lcd.setCursor(0,0);
           lcd.print("temp is : ");
           lcd.print(t);
           lcd.print(char(223));
           lcd.print("C");
           lcd.setCursor(0,1);
           lcd.print("Motion Detected");

       /*when motion is detected only that time LED will be on..  and stay     
       high for 200mSec then it will be off i.e. it will blink for once */       
           digitalWrite(pled,HIGH);
           delay(200);
           digitalWrite(pled,LOW);
           Serial.println("SMS INITIATING FOR MOTION...");
           //sendMsg(); to send "motion detected msg"

           Serial.println("DONE...");

           pirState=HIGH;

       }
    }
     else
    {
        if(pirState==HIGH)
        {
           Serial.println("Motion stopped     ");
           Serial.print("Temp is: ");
           Serial.print(t);
           Serial.print((char)223);
           Serial.println("C");
           lcd.setCursor(0,0);
           lcd.print("temp is : ");
           lcd.print(t);
           lcd.print(char(223));
           lcd.print("C");
           lcd.setCursor(0,1);
           lcd.print("Motion stopped     ");
           pirState=LOW;

        }
    }

    i++;
    delay(1000);
    }
digitalWrite(dled,LOW);
delay(500);   
}
/*
void SendMessage(float t )
{
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");    //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode
  delay(1000);  // Delay of 1000 milli seconds or 1 second
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"XXXXXXXXXX\"\r"); // Replace x with mobile     number
  delay(1000);
  mySerial.println("TEMP IS : ");// The SMS text you want to send
  mySerial.println(t);
  delay(100);
  mySerial.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z
  delay(1000);
}
void sendMsg(){
   mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");    //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode
   delay(1000);  // Delay of 1000 milli seconds or 1 second
   mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"XXXXXXXXXX\"\r"); // Replace x with mobile   number
   delay(1000);
   mySerial.println("MOTION DETECTED...");// The SMS text you want to send
   delay(100);
   mySerial.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z
   delay(1000);
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code is written in a blocking fashion using `delay(500);` and so on. You execute the PIR sensing 10 * 60 times and `delay(1000);` each, thus you expect 10 mins delay for the LED toggle. However, the inner `delay(200);` will lengthen the time spent inside the PIR loop, as you noticed.

You can address this problem in multiple ways, but the easiest would be to do LED events asynchronously using a global timeout timer. You set the timeout timer to 10 mins, turn the LED on and then after 10 mins, your timer interrupt calls the relevant timeout service routine which turns the LED off. Same goes for the second LED.

Your project might in general benefit from using some kind of RTOS instead of writing plain Arduino code.